# Wordpress querystring to friendly rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have the following URLs:

```
/products/?term_id=3
/products/?term_id=3&post_id=66
```

What I would like to get is the following:

```
/products/termid-termtitle
/products/termid-termtitle/postid-posttitle
```

Rewritten as the original URLs.

I've tried a few ones I have found elsewhere but to no avail.

Comment: Can you please share `few ones` rules you tried ?

Comment: @Milap As soon as they didn't work I removed them so I can't remember as I didn't keep them, sorry